# SOAP Request over https pfx file

Tags: php, soap, https

I got "a.pfx" file and "a.store" file from the provider, how to use these files in php?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post an example?

Is this what you're looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php